# How to retrieve the correct constructors of a class using RTTI?

Tags: delphi, rtti

I'm working with a class in Delphi defined as follows:

```
type
  TMyObject = class(TObject)
    constructor Create(a: string); overload; virtual;
    constructor Create(b: integer); overload; virtual;
  end;
```

I need to retrieve a list of constructors for `TMyObject` using RTTI. I attempted to use the `GetMethods('Create')` function of the `TRttiType` instance for `TMyObject`:

```
var
  Context: TRttiContext;
  RttiType: TRttiType;
  Method: TRttiMethod;
begin
  Context := TRttiContext.Create;
  RttiType := Context.GetType(TMyObject);
  for Method in RttiType.GetMethods('Create') do
  begin
    // Process method
  end;
```

However, I found that `GetMethods('Create')` also returns the Create method inherited from `TObject`, which isn't appropriate for creating `TMyObject` instances due to the additional parameters in TMyObject's constructors.

How can I use RTTI to get only the constructors of `TMyObject` that are usable for creating `TMyObject` instances? In other words, I want to exclude constructors inherited from `TObject` or other ancestors that cannot be used to properly initialize `TMyObject`. Is there a way to identify and filter out these inappropriate constructors using RTTI?

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you have noticed `GetMethods` function in `TRttiType` collects all methods in the class hierarchy.

But there is another method `GetDeclaredMethods` in `TRttiType` that will retrieve only methods declared in particular type and will not go down the ancestor list. However, this function does not have a parameter that will allows you to filter methods by name, so to get what you need you will need to write additional filtering function.

Something like:

```
function GetDeclaredMethods(AType: TRttiType; const AName: string): TArray<TRttiMethod>;
var
  Methods: TArray<TRttiMethod>;
  Method: TRttiMethod;
begin
  SetLength(Result, 0);
  Methods := AType.GetDeclaredMethods;
  for Method in Methods do
    begin
      if Method.HasName(AName) then
        begin
          SetLength(Result, Length(Result) + 1);
          Result[High(Result)] := Method;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Adding methods in above function is not optimized, so you might want to optimize that part, but it is also not extremely inefficient unless you have large amount of overloaded methods with same name declared in your classes.

Comment: In this case, since the OP is interested only in constructors, the enumeration could filter on that instead of/in addition to the name, using `TRttiMethod.IsConstructor`. Alternatively, the constructors could be renamed, ie `CreateByString()` and `CreateByInt()`, and then the standard `TRttiType.GetMethod()` would work.